# Python if statement retrieving "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, boolean

I have 2 datasets, a list `r` and a dataframe `df`.

```
r = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]

df

|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
| d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | d6 | d7 | d8 | d9 | d10|
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
|  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
|  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
```

I am trying to run an `if` statement that evaluates the selection of a random value from `df` vs `r`.
However I get an error.

The post in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) kind of exposes the problem and I did tried the methods but doesn't seem to be working.

I tried to used the methods proposed in the link above and in the error (`.any()`
  , `.all()`, `.bool()`) but don't see to get it working.

```
df1 = df.sample(n=1)
if(df1 <= r):
    df
    r-=df
```

I would expect for example if retrieving the first row of df, to have r assigned as below (r):

r = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve] that *includes a desired output*

Comment: check the type of df1 (just print it)

Comment: `any()`, `all()`, etc. are built-in functions. Don't use the dot operator to call them - do it like `if any(df1):` or something

Comment: Yes that does it, cheers @GreenCloakGuy.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` will raise an error because you are asking a comparison between two sets of data with more than one value each, which is ambiguous. Which is why numpy asks you to apply an `any()` or `all()` to pass it to an `if`.

As for your problem. You should define `r` as an array:

```
r = np.asarray(r)
```

Then, if all you want is to modify `r` (value by value and based on your comparison), do it with a mask:

```
df1 =  df.sample(1).values.ravel()   #to transform the row into a flat array
r -= (df1 * (df1<=r))
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is struggling with your if statement because it is comparing a list to a pandas dataframe object. You can easily convert the dataframe to a list and proceed the comparison. In the code below, I converted the values to a list and selected the first element, this is because the tolist() method will return a list of lists [[selected row]].

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1,size=(100,10)))
print(df.head(10))

r = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
rand_row = df.sample(n=1).values.tolist()[0]

if rand_row <= r:
    r = np.array(r) - np.array(rand_row)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve ... The answers above are a bit complicated, I would just go for something simpler such as using the fact

```
(a - b if a >= b else a) == a - b * (a >= b)
```

Then you can easily vectorize your operations:

```
# create some data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,2,(5,10)))
r = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
print(df.shape, len(r))
# for on row :
df1 = df.sample(1).values[0]
print(df1)
rslt =  df1 - r * (df1 >= r)
print(rslt)
# and straitforwadly for n rows:
rslt_manyrows = df - r * (df >= r)
print(rslt_manyrows)
```

And if you're considering, this solution is much, much faster than native pandas / iterative python.

Hope that helps!